# Configure Apache 2.4.7 for proxying socket.io

Tags: apache, sockets, proxy, websocket, socket.io

On our server we are running Apache already on port 80, on this same server I want to serve socket.io and I would like to connect to the socket.io server also on port 80. So I tried to get Apache to proxy port 80. I found this stackoverflow entry: https://serverfault.com/questions/616370/configuring-apache-2-4-mod-proxy-wstunnel-for-socket-io-1-0

What I did:

I enabled the next modules in apache:

```
a2enmod rewrite proxy proxy_wstunnel
```

I created a new site in '/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf', with the next content:

```
<VirtualHost subdomain.mydomain.com:80>
    Servername subdomain.mydomain.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3001/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:3001/socket.io
    ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:3001/socket.io
</VirtualHost>
```

On the same server I have the socket.io server running on port 3001:

```
server.listen('3001', function(){
  console.log('Socket.io server listening on *:3001');
});


io.listen(server).on('connection', function(client) {
    // Rest of the code
}
```

And the socket.io clients are connecting on this subdomain configured into apache:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://subdomain.mydomain.com/', {query: {extra_info : extra_info}});
```

Once I startup a client. I don't see anything coming into the socket.io server logging (I have added a lot of console.log() entries. All I see in the console of the client is the next error:

```
GET http://subdomain.mydomain.com:8100/socket.io/?extra_info=fe4567&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1416987210079-31 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

If I connect the clients directly to port 3001 of the socket.io server `http://subdomain.mydomain.com:3001` all is just working fine (when I open port 3001 on the apache server).

I am running the next versions:

- Apache: 2.4.7
- Socket.io server & client: 1.2.1

---

**EDIT:**

When I change the connection URL in `var socket = io.connect('http://subdomain.mydomain.com/', {query: {extra_info : extra_info}});` to `http://subdomain.mydomain.com:80`.

I receive a different error:

```
GET http://subdomain.mydomain.com/socket.io/?user_id=2&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1418122378582-40 
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://subdomain.mydomain.com/socket.io/?extra_info=sdferr&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1418122378582-40. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.178.158:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

I though setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in Apache would solve the issue, but it doesn't. I have added this to the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf`:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: where did this port come from `....com:8100/...` ? i could not see it in other config?!

Comment: I don't understand where the port 8100 comes from either. Can't find anything in the configuration files.

Comment: what about the client config? or code?

Comment: The client does not have any port config for port 8100. I connect the clients as described in the question

Comment: well, i am no expert in this but i see this as only reason, and technically it's ok cuz no port 8100 is configured so it's normal to get TIME_OUT, if i were you i will focus on finding where did the 8100 came from

Comment: @Yazan Completely true, but it is strange that I connect the clients with `io.connect('http://subdomain.mydomain.com/', {query: {extra_info : extra_info}})`, which should be port 80.

Comment: well, i will give you a couple of things you may try, not for sure, i will add as answer, as it may not be clear as a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There where 2 things going wrong. First of all, you need to specify port 80 in the client to be able to connect to port 80. So I configured the client to connect as follows:

```
io.connect('http://subdomain.mydomain.com:80/', {query: {extra_info : extra_info}})
```

After this change you will get several CORS issues. The only thing I needed to change is how the client JS file is retrieved. In my AngularJS application I included the socket.io client JS file as follows:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

I needed to change this to:

```
<script src="http://subdomain.mydomain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

It seems that the socket.io client is also served automatically by your socket.io server. If you retrieve the client JS from your own server you will get no CORS issues.

Comment: i deserve 50% of the bounty :(

Comment: oh i was kidding, you can revert if you want :) and if you keep it, many thanks!

Comment: Maybe @MarkVeenstra you have an idea as well for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel ? I am on this topic since days... but unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

based on our comments, here is some thing you may try, not for sure.

not sure how to pass both port and extra_info query, but the idea is to set port.

```
io.connect('http://subdomain.mydomain.com/', {port: 80})
```

or this

```
io.connect('http://subdomain.mydomain.com:80/', {query: {extra_info : extra_info}})
```

good luck.

Comment: Yazan, seems to be getting in the right direction. Bit strange, but adding the port 80 to the connection string in the client. Solves the first issue. But I no receive a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error. I tried to set this header in Apache, but still receiving this error. Any ideas?

Comment: well, that's strange, though 8100 is still exist in the error, i think that caused the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error as accessing site on different port is considered a different domain, so cross-domain policy is applied.

Comment: Would you have @Yazan any idea for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel?