# Nodejs can't establish a connection to the server at ws:// apache proxy

Tags: node.js, apache2

I am trying to configure my nodejs application to run on localhost with a domain name.

So my website on local is `http://app.local` which points to `http://localhost/app`

Now I have an app on nodejs which runs on 6060 port `http://localhost:6060`

I am trying to configure `localhost:6060` to work on `http://app.local/nodejs`

Here's my apache config file.

```
 <VirtualHost app.local>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@app.local
    ServerName app.local
    ServerAlias app.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/app

    ProxyPass /service http://localhost:3000
    ProxyPassReverse /service/ http://localhost:3000/

    ProxyPass /nodejs http://localhost:6060
    ProxyPassReverse /nodejs/ http://localhost:6060/

    ProxyPass /nodejs ws://localhost:6060
    ProxyPassReverse /nodejs/ ws://localhost:6060/

    <Directory >
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/app>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

My javascript code listen emits:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://app.local/', {path:'/nodejs/socket.io/', port: 6060});
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log("Connected");
});
```

When I try to run the app through this URL `http://app.local/nodejs`, it throws following error:

`Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://app.local/nodejs/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=NQ2LSn--THwZkrStAAAH.`

I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel) but still not working.

I am using Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Change

```
var socket = io.connect('http://app.local/', {path:'/nodejs/socket.io/', port: 6060});
```

to

```
var socket = io.connect('http://app.local:6060');
```

Comment: Why would this work? It seems like the same as he has put out before.