# Running Portainer in a Docker Container with Apache 2.4 mod_proxy and basic auth

Tags: apache, user-interface, docker, reverse-proxy, basic-authentication

Q: How do I configure Apache 2.4 as a reverse proxy for Portainer using Basic Authentication?

[Portainer](http://portainer.io/) is a UI for managing Docker container.
The Portainer documentation has a sample [nginx configuration](https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-configure-my-reverse-proxy-to-serve-portainer), but unfortunately none for apache.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A: You need to start Portainer with the flag --no-auth and use mod_proxy_wstunnel.

Start Portainer with [--no-auth](http://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html).
I use the following Docker Compose File:

```
portainer:
  image: portainer/portainer
  container_name: "portainer-app"
  privileged: true
  command: --no-auth
  ports:
    - 9000:9000
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /srv/docker/portainer/data:/data
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
  environment:
    TZ: "Europe/Berlin"
```

Configure Basic Authentication for your Apache domain.
Enable [mod_proxy_wstunnel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html).
Add the following to the configuration:

```
<Location /portainer/>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9000/
    RequestHeader set Connection ""
</Location>
<Location /portainer/api/websocket/>
    RequestHeader set Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    RequestHeader set Connection "upgrade"
    ProxyPass ws://localhost:9000/api/websocket/
</Location>
```

Comment: These settings are mostly working for me but unfortunately, I am unable to use the console functionality in Portainer. When trying to use the console, my apache log spits out the following error: 

    AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /portainer/api/websocket/exec. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have Portainer installed in Docker Swarm with Docker Flow Proxy, all behind Apache.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel) idea, I was able to successfully configure apache.

```
<Location /portainer/api/websocket/>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
  RewriteRule /portainer/api/websocket/(.*) ws://192.168.1.190:480/portainer/api/websocket/$1 [P]
</Location>
```