# Run apache server and node on same port

Tags: node.js

I am using MAMP server and node js.

My issue is that I want to run apache server and node on the same port, but solutions online are quite complicated as it does not server much of the purpose, also I am new to Node. 
I need a simple solution where I can node on the port of apache server.

Code is below,

it works fine, as everything is running on different port but I want the 'server' to run on port 8888 where apache is running. Or some way for node to interact with apache

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var mysql = require('mysql');
var router = express.Router();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'db',
    port : '8889'
});

server.listen(8888); <----- ERROR
console.log('server running.......');

connection.connect(function(error){
    if(!!error) {
        console.log('error in db connection');
    } else {
        console.log('db connected');
    }
});

app.use('/*', router);

router.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    console.log('hello there...');
});
```

Comment: I think that is not possible

Comment: Agree with @FrankRoth.

Comment: Frank Roth what i found on internet, most of solutions used http-proxy, but i am clueless about how to use it in my case..

Comment: it's impossible, you can reverse proxy (in apache) the port to the node port, to have you app e.g. cached on apache and server the static directly throw apache

Comment: @yellowsir can you show how?

Comment: @AtulKumar i posted a [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43653828/1761588)

Comment: It is impossible. A work-around is to use a proxy. But you think that's too complicated, so you're kind of out of options.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way to do this is to 'face' the Node service using Apache's Proxypass. This will forward a path to the node service running on a different port.

Adding the following to a your httpd.conf or under a vhost and restarting Apache should give you a working result

```
#I'm using 8890 for Node since your Apache runs on 8888 and DB is on 8889
ProxyPass /node/ http://localhost:8890/
ProxyPassReverse /node/ http://localhost:8890/
```

Navigating to http://localhost:8888/node/ will connect you to the node service running on port 8890.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `http-proxy` for that.

```
var http = require('http'),
httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer ({
    hostnameOnly: true,
    router: {
        '127.0.0.1':        '127.0.0.1:8080'
    }
});

proxyServer.listen(8888);
```

This will create a node process listening to port **8888**, and forwarding requested domains to **8080**.

Answer (score 0):

you will find many tutorials on this topic but here is a overview:

- you need apache mod [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)
- basicly setup you need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27534443/1761588),
  this link includes insturctions on how to set it up in a way, it will also forward your websockets (if you need that).
- you will use somethink like, `http://localhost:3005` where 3005 is the port nodejs runs on. (choose whatever port you like)
- it might be usefull to add this port to you iptables to prevent direct access (without apache)