# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for <AWS S3 url>

Tags: android, amazon-s3, android-volley

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for <AWS S3 url>
```

I'm getting this error while loading image onto an `imageView` using `Volley` library in `android`.

Here is code:

```
 VolleyCustomImageLoader mImageLoader;
 mImageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
 mImageLoader.get(URLPath, 
                VolleyCustomImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView,
                R.drawable.ic_user, R.drawable.ic_user));
```

Comment: What is your URLPath?

Comment: can you share the URLPath which you are trying to access

Comment: https://consumerappdev.s3.amazonaws.com/AccountImageFolder1514544401397JPEG_20171229_161631_-1445100522_cf128d07-c180-48b0-bd6f-f109de53c4f7.jpg

Comment: Can you share the code for `VolleyCustomImageLoader `?

Answer (score 2):

You should go through these [AWS S3 error codes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html#RESTErrorResponses) & **verify Http Headers** being sent while making request in **VolleyCustomImageLoader**

Try printing VolleyLogs using

```
VolleyLog.DEBUG = true;
```

and see any other significant info you can get from it, you can share that log too as part of the question.

Though, I am able to HTTP Get image URL you provided in comments.

Guessing you might not have shared actual URL with which you are facing issues due to privacy concerns?.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's Proxy issue. However, change the domain to a real IP address 
exp; https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png 
to https://31.13.71.36/images/fb_icon_325x325.png

if Not Worked!
you may need to configure WStunnel, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27526281/7569106) to relate