# Apache proxy with HTTP and WS protocols

Tags: http, websocket, mod-proxy, apache2.4

I have a service running on my server, it is possible to access it through http and ws. I have the dilemma when I am going to configure the subdomain in Apache2, because I would like to have both protocols working for the same subdomain. That is, if the incoming connection is using the HTTP protocol (`http://`) then Apache2 must redirect the connection to `SERVICE:HTTP_PORT`, if it is websocket (`ws://`) I want it to go to `SERVICE:WS_PORT`. Is there any way to do this without having to use routes like / ws or / websocket to make the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate for [WebSockets and Apache proxy : how to configure mod_proxy_wstunnel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel)

I followed the instructions of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35141086/4763630

This is the final Apache2 config for my server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ServerName service.example.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade}   =websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)     wss://service.example.com/$1 [P,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade}   !=websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)     https://service.example.com/$1 [P,L]

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ServerName service.example.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:1886/$1 [P,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:1996/$1 [P,L]
  ProxyPassReverse /          https://service.example.com

  <Location "/">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

  </Location>

  SSLEngine On
  SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLHonorCipherOrder On
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM

  SSLCertificateFile cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile chain.pem

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I can access with `http://`, `https://`, `ws://` and `wss://`.