# NextJS breaks when proxypass apache

Tags: reactjs, apache, next.js, proxypass

I want to deploy my nextjs app to my server. i started server with "npm run start". it runs on localhost:3000. Then I proxypass localhost:3000 to domain of my website. I edited apache conf file like this:

[image]

and now when i go to my website from my domain I'm getting a lot of errors in console and app doesnt work well. functionality breaks. it fails to load chunks and show me in console "is true hostaname: false". I don't know what to do now. help, plz.

Comment: All the js files are loaded?

Comment: @felixmosh no. https://muffin-candy.ru/ you can see in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention there are many `404` on js files.
[image]

You need to add a mapping between `_next/static` -> `.next/static` folder.

Comment: hm. Thank you. I will try and give you feedback

Comment: I added "distDir: '_next' in next config file and it helped. Thanks.

Comment: I've ran into the same issue but don't fully understand your response, please can you give an example?

Comment: try @OlegKusov solution, in your `next.config.js` file make the `distDir: '_next'`

Comment: ah my bad, I'm having this issue with HMR on dev, not with the build. My 404 is on `GET wss://[my-proxy-domain]/_next/webpack-hmr`. Also using apache. if you have any ideas, ty

Comment: It is related to the websocket that Next.js started to use, you need to proxy it as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel#answer-27534443