# Proxy passing setup for stomp over websocket on apache 2.4

Tags: apache, tomcat, centos, http-proxy, spring-websocket

I want to map a domain with my spring websocket deployed on server(tomcat) over port 8090.
I need to access my application through proxy passing over apache 2.4 installed on centOS.

> The application(.war file) is being accessed from a client build on
>   react and this client is on another server.

I followed  each step of below article but it is not working in my case.
Getting below error :

*WebSocket connection to 'ws://xyz/abc/greeting/251/lcnlhdwc/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400*

Please help me.

[WebSockets and Apache proxy : how to configure mod_proxy_wstunnel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel)

Comment: "not working" isn't a good description. On top: Please edit your question to be relevant to programming (stackoverflow's focus) or find a matching site on the stackexchange network. See [help/on-topic]. The [tag:apache] tag even mentions that it's explicitly for _programming_ questions as opposed to _configuration_ questions.

Comment: i have added error also

Comment: still a configuration question though, nothing about programming so far