# webrtc with node.js inside php based page

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, signaling

I have a website that i want to add some webrtc features to this project.I'm using sockect.io by node.js for signaling.
Pages have been coded in php. Users login to their accounts and start to answering the questions.I want the admin of the website beable to control the users using their webcams. So i want to add this feature using webrtc and node.js socket.io...but since node.js and Apache couldn't run in port 80 in a same time so i don't know how to combine these feature.....
Anyone doesn't have any idea to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the apache proxy module to proxy socket requests to the node server that ia running on different port

You can see here:
[WebSockets and Apache proxy : how to configure mod_proxy_wstunnel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/ddg#27534443)