# Apache reverse proxy for websockets

Tags: apache, websocket, reverse-proxy

I'm using Apache on my server to proxy traffic on port 80 and 443 out to separate VM's running different websites and services. I'm having trouble setting up a proxy for MeshCentral which requires websockets. I'm using Debian 10 with Apache 2.4.38.

I can load MeshCentral, but once I login it tries to use websockets and I get the following error;

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://example.com/control.ashx?auth=Uu7PBFNsswzzWoQaVNPH2N3ZwkWbx7DSsljaaY8cxthO5fcPVSz@sqLbGzyOpvxTxvfmV7WgwLdRklqLNYC5KQTjrZPCYDcNDvJ0AY7V8DGdUk68jK3sPfnc$Sl7rvhaQwR1xBukiZ8=. meshcentral.js:27:21
```

I've added the wstunnel proxy

```
a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
```

And setup HTTP and HTTPS proxies which work fine

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass        "/" "http://192.168.200.11/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://example.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond ${HTTP:UPGRADE} websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond ${HTTP:CONNECTION} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) "wss://example.com/$1" [P]

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass        "/" "https://192.168.200.11/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://example.com/"

    SSLProxyEngine On
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I've restarted apache before I tried loading the page in firefox and also tried google-chrome, same error.

Comment: Maybe similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

**Ubuntu**

`a2enmod proxy`

`a2enmod proxy_http`

`a2enmod proxy_wstunnel`

**Centos**

1. Open the module configuration file for proxies.
   sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-proxy.conf
2. All modules related to proxying are listed in this configuration file. Verify that the following lines exist and are uncommented.
   LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
   LoadModule proxy_wstunnel modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
3. If you made any changes to the file, save them now.
4. Restart Apache Web Server to apply your changes.
   sudo systemctl restart httpd

**Configuration:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName ws.serverlab.ca
  
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond ${HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
  RewriteCond ${HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
  RewriteRule .* "wss:/localhost:3000/$1" [P,L]
  
  <Proxy balancer://backend-cluster>
    BalancerMember http://server01:3000
    BalancerMember http://server02:3000
    BalancerMember http://server03:3000
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / balancer://backend-cluster/
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://backend-cluster/
  ProxyRequests off
</VirtualHost>
```

**ServerName ws.serverlab.ca**
The hostname of the virtual web host that will handle the WebSocket connections.

**RewriteEngine on**
Used to set the status of the RewriteEngine to either on or off. To support WebSockets it must be turned on.

**RewriteCond ${HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]**
A condition that must be matched in order for a request to be processed by the RewriteRule.

**RewriteCond ${HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]**
To something

**RewriteRule .* “wss:/ws-backend%{REQUEST_URI}” [P]**
Rewrite all incoming requests to use the wss protocol, and replace the destination hostname to that of a backend service.

Documentation from: [How to Reverse Proxy Websockets with Apache 2.4](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/how-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-with-apache-2-4/)

Comment: please can you help me with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70210654/httpd-websocket-error-upgrade-token-not-found-in-connection-header