# httpd websocket error, 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header

Tags: javascript, apache, websocket, virtualhost

I am deploying a Golang`(go1.16.7)` backend on a Namecheap vps, using Apache(`httpd...Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (centos 8)`)
Eveything works except the websocket connection.
The request is made to:

```
wss://editor.xyzw.com/crownies/ws/upload/file?email=gbenroscience@gmail.com
```

When I try to access the websocket connection, it gives:

```
the client is not using the websocket protocol:'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header
```

***(I printed this error out in the golang code in production)***

The websocket works locally in development, so I know the Golang code works well.
I am certain that the issue is somewhere with my vhost configuration in Apache.

Here is my vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName editor.xyzw.com
        ServerAlias editor.xyzw.com www.editor.xyzw.com http://www.editor.xyzw.com
        UseCanonicalName Off
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/editor_access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/editor_error.log
        DocumentRoot /path/to/my/document/root
    
    SSLEngine on
    
    SSLCertificateFile /opt/ssl/cert.crt
    
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/ssl/cert.key
    
    SSLCACertificateFile /opt/ssl/cert.ca-bundle
    
    
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    
    
    
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/ws(.*) ws://localhost:8080/crownies/ws/$1 [P,L]
    
    ProxyRequests off
    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
    </Location>
    
    
    
    </VirtualHost>
```

The request headers from Google Chrome:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Cookie: user=blah-blah-blah
Host: editor.xyzw.com
Origin: https://editor.xyzw.com
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: blah-blah-blah==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.55 Safari/537.36
```

Please what could be the issue with my vhost?

Answer (score 0):

I think `Location` takes precedence over rewrites, so when the *paths* overlap, you have to stick to rewrites. Don't forget to set proper timeouts for the backend too, for *example* (adjust to your needs):

```
# Worker Options
<Proxy http://localhost:8080>
    ProxySet keepalive=On smax=1 connectiontimeout=10 retry=10 timeout=30 ttl=15
</Proxy>

<Proxy ws://localhost:8080>
    ProxySet keepalive=On smax=1 connectiontimeout=10 retry=10 timeout=900 ttl=15
</Proxy>

# Rewrites
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade}    websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /ws/(.*) ws://localhost:8080/crownies/ws/$1 [P,L]

RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```