# Bitnami AMI Parse Server WebSocket connection failed over https

Tags: amazon-ec2, parse-server, bitnami, amazon-elb, aws-certificate-manager

I'm new to AWS EC2, I need your help, and let me know if you need more info so I can edit my question.

I'm stuck in the issue mentionned below, after setting up SSL in an EC2 instance based on Bitnami parse server image, I got the error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://base_url/parse/' failed: Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error"
```

I tried multiple solutions in the official doc, but it's not up to date, for example they ask you to add some config lines in a specific path, but when I SSH the instance I don't find that path, multiple things are changed, but the doc is not updated, so please anyone faced the same issue previously?

BTW I'm using Load balancer & AWS certificate manager.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it working fine with http?

Comment: No, same error even when calling the link over http

Comment: It may be related to your load balancer setup. What if you connect directly to the instance? does it work?

Comment: Hi @DaviMacêdo, I think it's not related to LB setup, because I reinstalled the instance and enabling SSL without using LB & ACM (Certificate Manager), still not able to setup LiveQueries, any idea how to do that? any changes needed in apache config?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel