# Attempting to reconnect to the server 1 of 8

Tags: apache, testing, proxy, blazor

Problem with Blazor Test application. I run this app. over Apache server with proxy:

```
 <VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set \"X-Forwarded-Proto\" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
 </VirtualHost>

 Listen 192.168.0.190:44366
# for ASP.NET app TestBlazor
  <VirtualHost 192.168.0.190:44366>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:44366/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:44366/
    ServerName 192.168.0.190:44366
  #  ServerAlias 192.168.0.190:44366
 </VirtualHost>
```

However, a message appears every minute: Attempting to reconnect to the server. Where can be problem ?
[Firefox console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOHBE.jpg)

Comment: Maybe the problem is that:
[2022-01-19T09:40:39.438Z] Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: There was an error with the transport.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:[WebSockets and Apache proxy : how to configure mod_proxy_wstunnel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel)

Virtual host must be configured as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set \"X-Forwarded-Proto\" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
 </VirtualHost>
 
  Listen 192.168.0.190:44366
# for ASP.NET app TestBlazor
  <VirtualHost 192.168.0.190:44366>
    ServerName 192.168.0.190:44366
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:44366/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:44366/$1 [P,L]
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:44366/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:44366/
 </VirtualHost>
```